# Flutter StreamBuilder complex widget freezes screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

The main page of our Flutter app is pretty "complex", as it is a CustomScrollView that embeds a list of horizontal ListViews, animations, and other widgets below the CustomScrollView.

We use a `StreamBuilder`, that displays an `CircularProgressIndicator` while the data is being fetched from our APIs, and then renders the whole page.

When the data is ready, we notice that there is a short delay (maybe 500ms) where the `CircularProgressIndicator` "freezes" while the page is being rendered.

If I replace the whole page by a simple `Container`, this behavior does not happen as everything is super fast to render; the indicator never never freezes.

**DEMO**

[video.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h-_OcmGjLt6IjeAibcUM-CaBsaMTrArp/view?usp=sharing) (Flutter 1.25.0-5.0.pre.140 / Debug / Physical Samsung S8)

**Simplified Sample Code:**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _myStream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              // Complex page widget that take time to draw, freezes indicator
              return _buildHomePage(data);

              // Counter-example, does not freeze because fast to draw
              return Container(color: Colors.blue);
            }
        )
    );
  }
```

How can I prevent this freeze behavior?

Comment: any error message in the console?

Comment: @SaifulIslam nope, nothing

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might be overwhelming the UI Isolate.  Have you looked at the timeline in DevTools?  If you're calculating in the UI Isolate, you might need to push that off into another calculate-only Isolate.

Comment: I haven't taken a look but I will! Can you give me more info about what you refer to as "calculating" or maybe share a link/article ?

Comment: IIf the timeline shows a long pause, you're probably calculating too much in the main thread (Isolate).  This article explains better: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a

Comment: I'm gonna try to test a few things, comment out some parts of the code see if anything is taking abnormal computation time. But as far as I know, we aren't making any heavy computation, actually no computation at all. Just fetching the data, passing it to the view that's all.

Comment: This would be easily cleared up if you posted this "// Complex page widget that take time to draw, freezes indicator,  return _buildHomePage(data);".  You're even saying it takes time to draw.  Why?  What are you doing in this draw?

Comment: I noticed this happens much more on debug than on release mode. And i'm not doing anything special, just rendering a carousel, a list of horizontal lists of images, lots of shadows...

Comment: What I see is the more i comment our elements in the tree, the less the activity indicator freezes. I was hoping to find one "big thing" that messed up the all rendering but seems like its just everything together